# Job Chaining in Celery - Passing Results

Tags: python, celery

I am trying to use a job [chain](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#chains) in celery (4.10).

I have the following three functions used in a job chain.

```
parameter_1 = "This is a parameter"
parameter_2 = "This is another parameter"

def validate_user(user_credentials)
    ...
    return validate_result

def register_user(validate_result, parameter_1)
    ...
    return registration_result

def update_user(validate_result, registration_result, parameter_2)
    ...
    return update_result

result = chain(
    validate_user.s(user_credentials),
    register_user.s(parameter_1), # validate_result will be available in **kwargs
    update_user.s(parameter_2) # registration_result will be available in **kwargs, but I can not access validate_result
    ).apply_async()
```

Can someone please point out what I am doing wrong, why I can not pass `validate_result` to `update_user` in the job chain.

Or this the wrong model and I should use something like [Task Classes](https://celery.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#custom-task-classes) for a case like this?